# maintaining rep invariants in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop, error-handling, setter, invariants

I'm new to Objective-C and trying to figure out what the best way of maintaining the rep invariant of a class is, given that exceptions aren't really an appropriate way of enforcing them. A good example of where this would come up is in the `Fraction` class that serves as an example in Kochan's *Programming in Objective-C*, which has this setter method:

```
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d {
    self.denominator = d;
}
```

So say part of your rep invariant demands `self.denominator != 0`. In Java, for instance, the most straightforward way to enforce that invariant would be to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if 0 is passed, but that doesn't make sense in Objective-C. An alternative would be to add an `NSError**` pointer argument to report the problem, but that seems both like it's overkill and like it doesn't suit the nature of the abstraction -- unlike, say, a database connection, we don't expect a zero denominator fraction to occur in normal use. So what's the cleanest solution here? Return an integer error code? Something else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`NSAssert()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW14):

```
- (void)setDenominator:(int)d
{
    NSAssert(d != 0, @"denominator cannot be 0");
    self.denominator = d;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649224/846273)

> In Cocoa and iOS programmer, exceptions are used to indicate
>   non-recoverable programmer error. When an exception is thrown by the
>   frameworks, it indicates that the frameworks have detected an error
>   state that is both not recoverable and for which the internal state is
>   now undefined.

In such a case it's clearly an illegal non-recoverable state that would lead to a division by zero so it is perfectly legal to raise an exception

Specifically you can raise a `NSInvalidArgumentException` as others have suggested.

If you want to go deeper into the topic, you should check out the [Error Handling Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH201-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you think an exception would be inappropriate here. Barring any additional constraints, I would just raise an NSInvalidArgumentException.

Answer (score 1):

You can raise a `NSInvalidArgumentException` exception and/or place an `NSAssert` , the latter  will cause the program to exit in debug mode which is good so you can catch it in development if you abuse the api.

`[[NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArgumentException reason:reason userInfo:nil] raise];`