# How to use try catch in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wanna check the `UITextField` is `String` or number by using try catch.
But it seems doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)add {

    @try {
        double firstNumber = self.firstNumber.text.doubleValue;
        double secondNumber = self.secondNumber.text.doubleValue;

        Calculator *calcu = [[Calculator alloc] initWithFirstNumber:firstNumber andSecondNumber:secondNumber andOperation:@"+"];

        self.result.text = calcu.calculateTwoNumber;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        self.result.text = @"Please enter right number!";
    }
    @finally {

    }
}
```

Comment: Well I think the problem is that there's nothing in your `@try` that's throwing an exception...

Comment: Do not use `try/catch` for such a task. It's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: What do you think will throw an exception? Calling `doubleValue` on a string that doesn't actually have a number simply returns 0 as stated in the docs.

Comment: I have indented your code so that it renders properly.

Comment: Or sending a message to a `nil` value doesn't cause a crash. If `self.result` is nil, nothing happens.

Comment: try-catch should only be used for checking exception. If you want to validate the field, implement your own method to check if the text satisfies your requirements.

Comment: iOS is not Java. Exception are what they are named "Exceptions" and not error handlers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648952/objective-c-exceptions)

Answer (score 5):

Follow code:

```
    @try {
       self.labelName.text=[arrName ObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Something missing...");
    }
    @finally {

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

What Claus Bönnhoff wrote in the comments cannot be overemphasized: Objective-C is *not* Java or C#.

The accepted way to use exceptions in Obj-C is for unrecoverable errors, not simple flow control.

The answer to your question, then, is that exceptions should be used very rarely. In several years of iOS development, I haven't used them a single time. I also have not come accross them in anyone else's code.

I have, however, encountered exceptions thrown by the Obj-C runtime, which I suppose gives some indication of what their role might be.