# HockeyApp SDK - Logging Caught Exceptions in iOS

Tags: ios, hockeyapp

Is there a way to send caught exceptions in iOS ? I could implement it in Android using ExceptionHandler.saveException API in the HockeyApp SDK. What is the equivalent API in iOS ?

```
@try {
   // lines of code which can cause an exception
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
   NSLog(@"%@", exception.reason);
   // report to HockeyApp 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HockeySDK-iOS does not support this, as I already answered to your support requests on HockeyApp.

You need to modify the SDK and interact with PLCrashReporter to make this work. We have no plans to implement this ourselves at the moment.

Comment: See also this very elaborate answer on the topic by longtime Apple engineer Bill Bumgarner: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4649224/1188527