# Dealloc called without viewDidLoad being called (crash on removing KVO observer)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a `UITabBarController`, and my 3rd tab observes an array on a singleton data store (implemented in `viewDidLoad`).

Currently if I just log out (and change root view controller from `App Delegate`), the app will crash when `dealloc` is called on that 3rd tab with the message "cannot remove observer for the key path "X" because it is not registered as an observer.

Using breakpoints, I see that `viewDidLoad` is never called on this 3rd tab, however dealloc is being called when I sign out. What is going on? I assume the `UITabBarController` is holding a reference to the 3rd tab when I enter the storyboard, but does not "load" that tab. Yet iOS calls dealloc on it when I release the tab bar controller.

Should I use a boolean to track `viewDidLoad` execution, or try to remove the observer with a `@try` statement? Is there an overall better design for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May have found an even better solution. I add the observer in the method `initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`, which is called when the parent `UITabController` is loaded. I am using the storyboard which may be why I need to call override this method instead of regular `init`. Doing this now without the need for a `BOOL` flag or `@try` and no crashing.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [anObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:aKeyPath options:0 context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `@try`. Exceptions in Objective-C should always be [considered programmer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648952/objective-c-exceptions), and should be fatal.

As you say, use a boolean ivar set in `-viewDidLoad` to avoid this.

---

The view has not been loaded because views are only loaded when they are required for display.

---

Raw KVO can be dangerous and unwieldy. While not required to answer this question, [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) significantly improves the KVO experience.

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` is called before the view appears for the first time. `UITabBarController` is creating the relevant `UIViewController`, but the view is not loaded during creation. It is loaded on-demand, when a user visits the tab for the first time.

KVO removal is problematic, I don't think you can avoid using `@try` in `dealloc`. I would suggest to use [KVOController](https://github.com/facebook/KVOController): it's fairly easy to use and it would also handle all the edge cases for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to set whether or not KVO has been set up. Using @try can create memory management issues depending on the state of the app.