# what kind exception is a decimal number exactness error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Read about swift program exceptions in [NSExceptionName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexceptionname),the explanation about decimalNumberExactnessException confused me.What exactly is decimal number exactness error and what kind code could get a decimalNumberExactnessException?

Comment: Any feedback on the answer? Let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 3):

`NSDecimalNumber` has a precision of 38 decimal digits. That is large, but not unlimited. As an example, the sum of

```
let d1 = NSDecimalNumber(string: "12345678901234567890123456789")
let d2 = NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.000000000000000000123456789")
```

can not be represented as an `NSDecimalNumber`.

The default behavior is to ignore that precision loss and return the closest representable number:

```
let d1 = NSDecimalNumber(string: "12345678901234567890123456789")
let d2 = NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.000000000000000000123456789")

let d = d1.adding(d2)
print(d) // 12345678901234567890123456789
```

However, that default behavior can be changed, here is a simple example:

```
let handler = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: 0,
                               raiseOnExactness: true, raiseOnOverflow: true,
                               raiseOnUnderflow: true, raiseOnDivideByZero: true)
NSDecimalNumber.defaultBehavior = handler

let d1 = NSDecimalNumber(string: "12345678901234567890123456789")
let d2 = NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.000000000000000000123456789")

let d = d1.adding(d2)
// Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSDecimalNumberExactnessException',
// reason: 'NSDecimalNumber exactness exception'
```

The exception thrown in an `NSException` which can be caught in Objective-C with `@try/@catch` (but see [Objective-C Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648952/objective-c-exceptions) for some caveats). An `NSException` can *not* be caught from within Swift.

In Swift you can use `NSDecimalAdd` instead if you need to check the result for possible precision loss:

```
var d1 = Decimal(string: "12345678901234567890123456789")!
var d2 = Decimal(string: "0.000000000000000000123456789")!
var r = Decimal()
let err = NSDecimalAdd(&r, &d1, &d2, .plain) // NSDecimalNumber.CalculationError
print(err == .lossOfPrecision) // true
```